# Techniques for finding the edges of a 4-dimensional convex hull

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

I am looking for some techniques in general, but let's do it on a (for me relevent) example. I have a set of $n^2$ points

$$p_{i,j}:=\frac1{\sqrt 2} \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi i/n) \\ \sin(2\pi i/n) \\ \cos(2\pi j/n) \\ \sin(2\pi j/n) \end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^4,\qquad\text{for $i,j=1,...,n$}.$$

Let $P:=\mathrm{conv}\{p_{i,j}\}$ be the *convex hull* of all these points. Since all the points are on the boundary of the unit sphere of $\Bbb R^4$, they will form the vertices of $P$.

Now I wonder, what are the *edges* of $P$? My guess would be that the edges are formed by the vertex pairs

$$(p_{i,j},p_{i+1,j})\quad\text{and}\quad (p_{i,j},p_{i,j+1})$$

for all $i=1,...,n-1$, and no others. Currently I have no tools to show this easily. What would be the fastest/most elegant way to approach this problem?

Comment: Let $V=\{1/\sqrt2(\cos 2\pi i/n,\sin 2\pi i/n):i=1,\dots,n\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2$. Then $\{p_{ij}\}=V\times V$, so $P=\operatorname{conv}V\times\operatorname{conv}V$ too, isn't it? (*P.S.* I wish you'd called the point set $P$ and the convex hull $C$ or something...)

Comment: I believe the convex hull will be a [duoprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duoprism), with $2n^2$ edges.

Comment: @Rahul I called it $P$ for "polytope". Okay, I have not immediately known that $\mathrm{conv}(\{p_{i,j}\}\times \{p_{i,j}\})=\mathrm{conv}\{p_{i,j}\}\times \mathrm{conv}\{p_{i,j}\}$, but this would give an elegant way to show this. I still wonder about general techniques, if it's not just the cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

That special polytope in fact is the duoprism of two n-gons, as already was mentioned in the comments.

In the general case, when considering n arbitrary vertices within $\mathbb{R}^4$ and would be asking for the edges of the convex hull, you would first have to consider any subset of 4 vertices each, i.e. ${n\choose 4}$ selections, and derive the thereby spanned hyperplanes. Next you would have to determine the subset of those, which have the remaining vertices on just a single side thereof. Those are the bounding hyperplanes.

The subset of vertices contained within either of these bounding hyperplanes then reduces your problem by 1 dimension. That is, you would have some set of $m<n$ vertices in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which then defines some bounding cell by means of the same convex hull procedure. Thus you take all subsets of 3 therefrom in turn, i.e. ${m\choose 3}$ selections, providing you with a set of 2D planes. Then again you have to detect the subset of those, which have the remaining vertices (of this set of $m$ for sure) on a single side therefrom. These now are the bounding 2D planes

Finally you do the same dimensional reduction once again, in order to derive the searched for edges / bounding 1D lines.

--- rk