# Is there an algorithm to find the edge vectors of a polytope?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, polytopes

**Question:**

Given some points $x^1,\dots,x^m \in \mathbb R^n$, is there an algorithm that finds the vectors along the edges of the polytope
$$P = \mathrm{conv}(x^1,\dots,x^n)$$
formed by the convex hull of these points?

**Definitions:**

A **polytope** is the convex hull of finitely many points in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $P \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a polytope. A **face** of $P$ is a a subset $F \subset P$ of the form
$$F = \arg \max\{c^Tx : x \in P\}$$
for some $c \in \mathbb R^n$. The **dimension** of a face of $P$ is the dimension of its affine hull. A **vertex** is a face of dimension zero and an **edge** is a face of dimension one. If $E$ is an edge of $P$ then $E = \mathrm{conv}(x, y)$ for some vertices $x$, $y$. An **edge vector** of a polytope $P$ is a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $v=x-y$ for some vertices $x$ and $y$ for which $\mathrm{conv}(x,y)$ is an edge.

**Example:**

Let $x^1=(0,0), x^2=(1,0), x^3=(0,1), x^4=(1,1)$. The convex hull of these points is the square
$$P=\mathrm{conv}(x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4)$$
whose edge vectors are given by
$$\{(1,0), (0,1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)\}.$$
Note that $(1,1)=x^4-x^1$ is not an edge vector although it is the difference of two vertices.

Comment: Since you have tagged the question as linear programming I assume you know about the simplex algorithm. Perhaps there is some modification/extension of it that tracks the edge move as well?

Comment: You could examine all $\binom m 2$ pairs $(x^a,x^b)$ of vertices, and for each pair, use LP to tell if $(x^a+x^b)/2$ is in the convex hull of the other $m-2$ points.

Comment: @cgss The simplex method requires that the polytope is given by a set of inequalities rather than a convex hull of points. But in general, yes, linear programming should be the way to go.

Comment: @kimchilover If the midpoint is not in the convex hull of the other points, this gives no guarantee that this pair of vertices forms an edge (think of a triangle of points and another point in the center).

Comment: I was assuming your $x^a$ points were all extreme points.  Sorry!

Comment: @M.Winter It's not something very concrete but intuitively I would think there must be some method to form an equivalent problem with the convex hull of points rather than the inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a first step you have to determine which points are vertices of the convex hull.
In a second step you can proceed as explained by kimchi in the comments.

A point $x_i$ is a vertex of $\mathrm{conv}\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ if

$$\max \{p^\top\! x_i\mid p^\top\! x_j \le 1 \text{ for all $j\not=i$}\}$$

is unbounded.

If $x_i,x_j$ are vertices, to determine whether $\mathrm{conv}\{x_i,x_j\}$ is an edge of the convex hull you can proceed as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2913477/415941).
You have to iterate this over all ${n\choose 2}$ vertex pairs.
If it is an edge, you just compute $x_i-x_j$ to get its direction.

To compute the maxima in all these cases you will have to use linear programming algorithms which are standard and have many well-developed implementations (e.g. in Mathematica or MATLAB).